Excel use a range format when the numbers are in a sequence (changing 1,2,3,4 to "1-4")
I have some numbers in a cell in this format:
1,2,3,4,10,12,13,14,15
and I want to show it as below:
1-4,10,12-15
What I mean is to use a range whenever the numbers are in a sequence (e.g., from 1 to 4 instead of 1,2,3,4).
Is it possible using the Excel functions or should I write a VBA for this?
Thanks.

What have you already tried?

@Randomhero, The question isnt about how to write it, but is it possible.

You can also use UDF function like this:
Function Connect(list As String) As String
    list = Replace(list, " ", vbNullString)
    list = "A" & Replace(list, ",", ",A")
    list = Union(Range(list), Range(list)).Address(0, 0)
    list = Replace(list, "A", vbNullString)
    Connect = Replace(list, ":", "-")
End Function


In Office 365 you could try:
=LET(t,--TEXTSPLIT(A1,,","),w,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(IF(ISNA(XMATCH(t+{-1,1},t)),t,e),2),2),x,TAKE(w,,1),y,DROP(w,,1),ARRAYTOTEXT(IF(x-y,x&-y,x)))
